# jQuery, pass a variable to append()

Tags: jquery

This one works, actually:

```
$('.open-submenu > a').append("<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>");
```

I would like to change the former to:

```
var open-string = "<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>";
$('.open-submenu > a').append(open-string);
```

but it seems not working...I tried also `$('.open-submenu > a').append('' + open-string);` and `$('.open-submenu > a').append("" + open-string);` but still doesn't work...is it possible to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable name is invalid since it includes `-` in your variable name. To make it valid replace the `-` character from the variable name.

```
var open_string = "<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>";
$('.open-submenu > a').append(open_string);
```

---

For more info : [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

MDN Docs : [Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name is invalid because of the `-` character, which isn't allowed in JavaScript variable names.

Change to:

```
var openString = "<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>";
$('.open-submenu > a').append(openString);
```

Remember to check the console for errors, because this will be producing an error which helps to find the problem:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -